# How do I repair a small nick in motor windings?

Tags: electrical, repair, appliances

I accidentally put a nick in a washing machine motor's windings when I was removing it. The nick is shallow, with mostly just the varnish scraped off, and isn't as big as the picture makes it look. Thankfully I only nicked one wire. I looked into buying another one, but they are pretty expensive.  [image]

Thanks

Comment: Use shellac! It was commonly used on early electric motors and has excellent insulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the conductor in the motor winding is undamaged, you can probably repair the insulating varnish with a product that is made for that purpose.

Here is the tech sheet to one such product, MG Red Insulating Varnish 4228:

http://www.mgchemicals.com/downloads/tds/tds-4228-l.pdf

Amazon stocks and sells 55ml bottles of this for about $10.

Comment: Thanks. Although the tech sheet mentions it's okay for the varnish to air dry, the manufacturer highly recommends baking it on for "optimal
dielectric properties". What does this mean?

Comment: That means the product does not achieve the rated 3000v/mm insulation value unless baked in an oven (such as would be done when manufacturing new equipment).  You cannot bake your motor because that would ruin it.  Notice that the varnish is rated 1500 volts/mm wet out of the bottle before it has cured at all.  It should be good enough for your repair.   Your motor is 120v or 220v depending where live in the world.